# How to use cv2.findHomography() with Squeezed Images

Tags: python, opencv, stretch, homography

I am using the python bindings for opencv. I am using keypoint detection and description (ie SURF, SIFT,...) to find a template image contained within a target image, but there is a catch: the template can be "squeezed" in the target image, so that the aspect ratio is different than the target image.

This does not work with findHomography(), since it assumes a simple perspective transform, which cannot have this sort of stretching.

Are there any ways to do this? I have thought about incrementally stretching the target image different amounts to change the aspect ratio, and using findHomography at each iteration, but as far as I can tell there is no way of comparing the quality of a fit (since I'm using RANSAC to find the best fit), so I can't tell at which squeeze level it fits best.

Perhaps counting the number of points that matched correctly from the RANSAC by looking at the length of the returned mask? This seems sorta gross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not work with findHomography(), since it assumes a simple perspective transform, which cannot have this sort of stretching.

This is not true; even an affine warp includes [stretching the aspect ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) and even shear distortion, and homographies expand this by even non-uniform distortions. For example, the affine transformation given by the matrix

```
2 0 0
0 1 0
```

will stretch an image horizontally by a factor of two, as seen with this short program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
affine_warp = np.array([[2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
dsize = (img.shape[1]*2, img.shape[0])
warped_img = cv2.warpAffine(img, affine_warp, dsize)

cv2.imshow("2x Horizontal Stretching", warped_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Producing the output:[image: Lena stretched 2x wide]

So that is not your issue. Homographies allow even stronger warping. Are you running `RANSAC` yourself or letting the `findHomography()` function decide your points via `RANSAC`? Please post your expected output and your current code, possibly in a new question that reflects the problems you're facing.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. My code was working correctly, I was mistaken when I thought that my images were stretched, they were actually just padded with some extra stuff on the sides. I misunderstood the wikipedia article on Homography which says a homography relates " any two images of the same planar surface," which I thought meant the SAME image on a surface. I didn't realize that it could encode an affine transformation too. Thanks!